# correct usage - using was/am with "said"

Tags: grammar, tenses, indirect-speech, sequence-of-tenses

Which one is correct:

> My manager told me that I **was** not doing great at work.

or

> My manager told me that I **am** not doing great at work.

Comment: Neither is correct at the moment. Please can you use capital letters properly. Thank you.

Comment: @tchrist - I sort of see what you are getting at but the verbs in this question are simple present and simple past.

Comment: My question is more around the using the present tense with the past tense. which one is correct

My manager told me that I was not doing great at work

or My manger told me that I am not doing great at work.

Answer (score 2):

Both are *past reports* ("told") of your manager saying directly "You are not doing great at work."  To make the statement make sense in a report, you have to shift the person to **first** from second -- "*told* me that **I** ...." and you have a choice of verb tenses in the report.

You may backshift to the **past** to accommodate the past report:  "that I **was** not doing great work."

Or you may keep the present tense if the report is still true:  "that I am not doing great work."

Comment: I agree.  Additional comment:  The first is an opinion about a specific past time period.  The second is a judgment, a global statement about your work in general.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is only right undoubtedly. You need to use the same tense unless the content of the indirect speech is about a *fact* that doesn't change over time.

For example we can say:

> He told me that the sun rises from the east.

I think in colloquial language, the second one COULD (that's a big could) be used by some people, but still it's not right.